# Tic Tac Toe game with small looping error

Tags: java

I have my tic tac toe game coded here for my java assignment and everything works great except for one small problem that is when you enter the last move (the ninth turn) the very last 'X' does not show up. Not only is this just annoying as the winning piece is not shown, but it leads to some problems with the tie method not being addressed to properly, thus it showing nothing.

I know specifically why it is not doing this, just need help fixing it.

```
do
 {
     ComputerSpotChoice = (int) (Math.random() * 9 ) + 1 ; 
 }
 while (Board [(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) / 3] [(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) % 3] != '-') ;
```

When it enters the ninth turn, this condition is always true as it can not find '-'. Goes on infinite loop and am not too sure how to fix this, but keep the computer spot selection semi the same.

Here is the full code.

```
/*I have methods for drawing the board, determining a winner, and a loser. This is just the 'main' method containing the bulk of the program */

    public static void main (String[] args)
        {
        //Variable declaration
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        char [] [] Board = new char [3] [3] ;
        String MenuInput ;
        int BoardOutput ;
        int UserSpotChoice ;
        int ComputerSpotChoice = 0;
        int UserTurn = 1 ;
        int Winner = 0 ;
        Board [0] [0] = '-' ;
        Board [0] [1] = '-' ;
        Board [0] [2] = '-' ;
        Board [1] [0] = '-' ;
        Board [1] [1] = '-' ;
        Board [1] [2] = '-' ;
        Board [2] [0] = '-' ;
        Board [2] [1] = '-' ;
        Board [2] [2] = '-' ;

        //Welcome
        System.out.println ("Welcome to Alex Montague's Tic Tac Toe game!") ;
        System.out.println ("") ;
        System.out.println ("If you wish to play, type 'Play'") ; 
        System.out.println ("If you wish to read the instructions, type 'Instructions'") ;
        System.out.println ("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'") ;
        MenuInput = kbReader.next () ;

        do
        {
        if (MenuInput.equals ("Play") || MenuInput.equals ("play")) 
        {
            while (!GameOver) 
            {
            System.out.println ("\f") ;
            System.out.println (" Tic Tac Toe") ;
            BoardOutput = DrawBoard (Board) ;
            System.out.println (" 1 2 3") ;
            System.out.println (" 4 5 6") ;
            System.out.println (" 7 8 9") ;
            System.out.println ("Please enter the number you would like to move your spot to") ;
            UserSpotChoice = kbReader.nextInt () ;

            if (UserSpotChoice == 1) Board [0] [0] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 2) Board [0] [1] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 3) Board [0] [2] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 4) Board [1] [0] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 5) Board [1] [1] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 6) Board [1] [2] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 7) Board [2] [0] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 8) Board [2] [1] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 9) Board [2] [2] = 'X' ;

            do
            {
                ComputerSpotChoice = (int) (Math.random() * 9 ) + 1 ; 
            }
            while
            (Board [(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) / 3] [(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) % 3] != '-') ;

            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 1) Board [0] [0] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 2) Board [0] [1] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 3) Board [0] [2] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 4) Board [1] [0] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 5) Board [1] [1] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 6) Board [1] [2] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 7) Board [2] [0] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 8) Board [2] [1] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 9) Board [2] [2] = 'O' ;

            Winner (Board) ;
            Loser (Board) ;
            Tie (Board) ;

            } //While loop
            if (GameOver) System.exit (0) ;
     } //If play

        else if (MenuInput.equals ("Instructions") || MenuInput.equals ("instructions")) 
        {
            System.out.println ("\f") ;
            System.out.println ("You will be playing the game of Tic Tac Toe against the computer.") ;
            System.out.println ("The object of this game is to get three of your own x's or o's in a line.") ;    
            System.out.println ("You take turns placing the x's and o's and whoever gets three in a row first wins.") ;
            System.out.println ("Good Luck!") ;
            System.out.println ("") ;
            System.out.println ("If you wish to play, type 'Play'") ;
            System.out.println ("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'") ;
            MenuInput = kbReader.next () ;
        }

        else if (MenuInput.equals ("Exit") || MenuInput.equals ("exit")) 
        {
            System.out.println ("Thank you for using Alex Montague's Tic Tac Toe game!") ;
            System.exit (0) ;
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println ("Sorry, that is not a valid choice.") ;
            System.out.println ("If you wish to play, type 'Play'") ; 
            System.out.println ("If you wish to read the instructions, type 'Instructions'") ;
            System.out.println ("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'") ;
            MenuInput = kbReader.next () ;
        }

        } //do while
        while (!MenuInput.equals ("Instructions") || !MenuInput.equals ("instructions") || !MenuInput.equals ("Play") || !MenuInput.equals ("play") || !MenuInput.equals ("Exit") || !MenuInput.equals ("exit")) ;

        } // main method
```

Comment: Your code would be a lot easier to read if you used lowerCamelCase for your variables. Take a look at the Google style guide for some inspiration. https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.3-camel-case

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Tic Tac Toe Small Loop Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810503/java-tic-tac-toe-small-loop-error)

Answer (score 0):

Why not randomize a list of the possible moves at the start, and simply go through the list?  That way your loop has to end.  Not only doesn't your current loop recognize when the game is over, but can try the same illegal move repeatedly.

Here's one approach that doesn't involve sorting: add these definitions:

```
char free[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // choices not taken yet
int numFree = 9;                    // number of choices available
int moveIndex;
```

Then choose a move like so:

```
moveIndex = (int) (Math.random() * numFree);   // pick index of new move from free ones
ComputerSpotChoice = free[moveIndex];          // save that choice
numFree--;                                     // there is now one less free move
free[moveIndex] = free[numFree];               // move the "last" free move to where you just took a move from
```

You'll need to search 'free'  for the user's choice so it can be removed.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I was trying to just make it random by generating a random number, then assigning that number to a specific move, which worked pretty good. Just having the loop problem here.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I just tried this out in my code and it there still seems to be some weird things going on such as whenever I place my 'X' the computer 'O' you told me to use removes my 'X' and places itself there, and still doesn't show the last move. Any ideas? I will try to debunk this my self and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your program is relying on chance to find the last available move.
This is a bit strange - would you put numbers back into a hat after randomly pulling them out?
Nope, you'd leave them out of the hat.

Scott Hunter suggests that you make a list of randomly ordered moves first. To continue the analogy this is to pull the numbers out of the hat before hand.

You don't have to do this up front. You could also create list given the current board state, and then randomly choose from this list.

The basic idea is...

1. Generate a list of possible moves
2. Randomly choose from this list (if the list is empty, then no moves are possible).

Hint: You can represent a board cell using a single value...

```
Given a board[x][y] then...
cell = x * 3 + y
x = cell / 3
y = cell - x * 3
```

Comment: I feel like this would help my situation, but unfortunately am not exactly sure what you mean here. Thanks for the answer though.